# Core Graphics contexts, what are they?

Tags: ios, uikit, drawing, core-graphics, quartz-2d

This might be an entirely inappropriate question for StackOverFlow, but I don't know where else to turn, **having read a bunch of online stuff about them***, I'm stuck on understanding what a context actually is. And why, how, where it exists.

Existential questions, I know, but I'm trying to grok these things.

/* YES, including the relevant Apple documentation, I've read much. ASSUME I'm stupid, and try to answer the following questions about what the Context is in a way that's simpler, easier to understand and perhaps even more prescient than the technically obfuscated guff and shortcut abbreviations of "you just need it" that's written by all others.  If you can't do that, then feel free to be as derogatory and demeaning to me as you like. */

Contexts?
How many of them there are, do they have names or other IDs, can they be sorted, transformed (rotation, position, scale, skew and opacity changes). Can they be layered, or are they somehow fixed to something else, and is that a children or parent kind of relationship? Can they be linked or nested???? etc etc.

I just don't get what they are, at all.  Yes, before you ask, I do feel stupid for not instantly grokking something that everyone else seems to just "get" by referring to them as "contexts".

I see that I have to draw to these things, that nothing happens if I don't but that's about the end of the possible comprehension of what, why and how they came to be/are, and their need, potential, practical uses are all, for lack of a better term, invisible.

I'm completely flummoxed as to what these things are.

**EDIT: Addition.**
Taking an example from the docs:

"A bitmap graphics context accepts a pointer to a memory buffer that contains storage space for the bitmap. When you paint into the bitmap graphics context, the buffer is updated. **After you release the graphics context, you have a fully updated bitmap in the pixel format you specify.**"

Ok... release, and have, (where), what can be done with this? Where was it released to, and from?

Is this the most obtuse possible way of saying that a context is a "pretend" representation of the screen area available to draw into without directly drawing on the screen, and that this can then be mapped onto the screen? Is this blotting? Does this get massively memory intensive when doing full screen retina iPad graphics drawing?

If so... wouldn't it make sense that this context has a transform?  That it can be rotated, scaled and repositioned relative to where it's going to be drawn?  Can it therefore be duplicated and rotated?

If it's transformed, how are its contents scaled without aliasing issues. etc etc.

Does this mean there can be more than one context of the same type, and that they can be blended with different levels of opacity and different blend modes?

These documents only seem to partially explain, at best, what this thing is.  It seems that it's right there, easy to grasp for everyone but me.

Is there anyone that can simply explain wtf it IS? Because even a vague effort at explaining what a context is might set me on the right path to instantly getting all the rest.

Comment: Are you asking about CGContext or CIContext? You mention Core Image but you tagged the question Core Graphics.

Comment: Very sorry. That should have been Core Graphics in the title. I have no interest in Core Image.

Comment: You have read the first 3 chapters/sections in the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007533-SW1), right? They are **Introduction**, **Overview of Quartz 2D**, and **Graphics Context**. That's a pretty good place to start.

Comment: Yes, read everything I can find, many times over. NOTHING details what they are. It's just described as something that's needed, that you draw to.

Comment: the first paragraph in [Guide:Graphics Contexts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html) explains what it is. a few paras after that it explains that you get one with a `UIView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CoreGraphics context represents drawing state. It contains things such as the current transformation matrix, the width and height of any lines to be drawn, the fill color, the stroke color, and a bunch of other information about how the computer should draw things. You can imagine it as some sort of C struct (though whether it is or not is irrelevant - it might be a C++ object, an Objective-C Object, or something else). It might look something like this:

```
struct CGBitmapContext {
    void* bitmapData;
    UInt32 rowBytes;
    float currentTransform [4][4];
    float lineWidth;
    CGColorRef fillColor;
    CGColorRef strokeColor;
    // ... other graphics state needed for drawing ...
};
```

When you issue commands to draw, such as calling [`CGContextFillRect()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17024), it uses that state to decide how and where to draw. It will transform the rectangle you passed in using the current transformation matrix, then fill it in with the fill color.

But you don't deal directly with a `CGContext`. Instead, you have a `CGContextRef`, which is a pointer to the above struct (or object, or whatever it really is). So the context resides at the address pointed to by the `CGContextRef`. When you call [`CGContextRelease()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17034), if the retain count for the context is 0, then the memory for the struct or object or whatever, is freed, probably using `free()`, or `delete` or `-release`.

You can have as many contexts of any type as will fit in memory. They are all independent. If you are using bitmap contexts, freeing the context does not necessarily free the bitmap data. (I believe it depends on how you created the context.) You can use the data from various contexts to blend together, if you want. You could make CGImages out of them if you want, or upload them to the video card for use with OpenGL. You can do whatever you want with them.

In the days of MacOS 9, this was much more confusing because there were not contexts. You had to set the state every time you wanted to draw. And if you weren't careful, a previous function may have set the state to something odd. If you didn't notice the state had changed, and didn't change it back to what you wanted, the drawing would look bad. With a context, you can save the state and restore it using `CGContextSaveGState()` and `CGContextRestoreGState()`, and you can use different contexts for drawing to different views within the same window, for example. This greatly simplifies drawing.

Comment: Ok. I get stuck on basics. Contains "current transformation matrix"... of what? The CGContext? The View it's guessing I'm aiming at eventually drawing the Context into? The object I'm currently drawing to the Context? Something else entirely.

Comment: It seems the Context is kind of like a buffer. It's possibly even a 1:1 mapping of whatever visual space it is supposed to represent, from what I can gather, and uncompressed. So a huge memory drain. And probably an array of bytes for each pixel in the ... context! (sorry)

Comment: The current transformation matrix for drawing. Every coordinate you pass in to every function like `CGContextAddLineToPoint()` or `CGContextDrawImage()` or `CGContextFillRect()` gets transformed by (that is, multiplied by) the current transformation matrix. I believe that by default, with a `CGBitmapContext`, the matrix is set to identity and 1 pixel is equal to 1 unit in the coordinate space. If you scale, rotate, or translate the matrix, that relationship changes. Scale by 2, and 1 pixel equals 2 units, etc.

Comment: In the case of a `CGBitmapContextRef`, there is indeed a pixel buffer that's an array of bytes for each pixel. But that might not be the case for, say, a `CGPDFContextRef`. Instead of actually drawing into memory, it may just allocate drawing commands to write to a file. In general, the word "context" means, "a set of data that describes the state of something."

Comment: I hate that hitting the return key sends a comment. These were meant to be all one comment with paragraphs. My final point being that what it is, why it exists and what its intended purposes/advantages/reasoning etc are aren't coming to me even if I think of it as a memory dump zone for the potential graphics to later be kind of blit onto the screen.

Comment: So the reason we use a context is so that you can do different drawing to different things without getting them confused. When drawing to one window or view, you might want to set the background color to white with black text, but for another you might want a blue background with yellow text. There are 2 ways this is usually done - either each window or view has a context that says what the background color and text color are, or you have to set them every time you draw, and it becomes complex to keep track of how things are set whenever you want to draw something. That's how OS 9 worked.

Comment: I've added to the answer to explain the last point a little better.

Comment: That last little bit, about the reasoning for the existence of contexts, shone a VERY bright light down a very dark tunnel. Now... just gotta figure out all the machinations versus the obscured realities. And take some wisdom pills. Lots of them.

Answer (score 0):

After conversing with a few fine folks that understand my sensibilities for metaphorical understanding of things, it appears Contexts might be a bit like this:

Contexts are like a special kind of SilkScreen for "printing" imagery onto clear plastic overhead projector sheets that are then placed in frames to be presented to users via an overhead projector.

In this "metaphor" a View is the frame that holds a unique clear plastic sheet and the plastic sheet is a CALayer.

Contexts are each uniquely related to a CALayer, and might be best thought of like a silkscreen that an image, drawing or other artwork can be drawn on before, at our leisure, being transferred to its related clear plastic overhead projector sheet, the CALayer, which is presented to the user by way of the frame (View) that holds it and places it on the screen.

This silk screen can be rotated or otherwise positioned before we draw into it.

So doing something like printing the digits of a clock face in position around from 12 to 11 can be done by rotating the silk screen (context) and printing to the same "location" through each 360/12 degree rotation of the context.